# Geometry Nodes: Ignore specific points from a resampled curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a generator that creates the classic "light poles with hanging flags attached in-between each pole".
My approach is simple, I add a light pole mesh on each point of the curve, then resample the curve and add flags on it. So far, so good, you can see the result on the image below.

My problem is that I don't want hanging flags on the same spot the light pole is, and I can't figure out how to solve this.

As you can see on the node setup, I've tried using an "Endpoint Selection" node to remove the points at the start and end of the curve, thus only adding the hanging flags in the middle section.
The problem is that this takes the whole curve into account, and I want it to work on each section between each pole.

So, what I'm trying to find is some way to take the points from the original curve, and remove them from the selection on the resampled curve.
Is there a way to run a comparison between the points of two curves?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll give you a non-perfect solution, but it's fast. you take the index and put it through a math node set to modulo and set to 2. then capture that before resample, then after resampling use a ping-pong math on the value that comes out of the capture set to 1 (or .5 or 2, I'm not sure) then compare it not equal to 0 and the epsilon will the spread.  this will be the selection of the instance on points